# ld linker doesn't compile win64 object file

Tags: assembly, mingw, nasm, ld, win64

Whenever I try to create a program in NASM, I have two options that work: create a win32 executable (which doesn't work on my x64 machine) or make a win64 object/output file. I used NASM to create a win64 object file, then attempt to link it with these commands:

`nasm -f win64 -o output.o input.asm`

`ld input.o -o output.exe`

The error message from MINGW `ld` is:

`Example.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized`

Comment: You built LD on Windows? You're sure LD is your linker?

Comment: Ahh now I get it. Do you know what I should use instead?

Comment: I *believe* you need the ELF format for LD, but it *should* still create a PE file when using MinGW (I'm not 100% sure). If you want to use a more native linker, I would suggest you use GoLinker @ http://godevtool.com/ (Not related to the language by the same name). I've had good experience with this linker.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Any time! I'm always happy to help!

Comment: Yeah I kinda didn't put two and two together on this one .___.

Comment: It's assembly; the smallest things (and I mean *smallest*) can slip you up. :P

Comment: By far, the worst kind are the ones the assembler doesn't complain about.

Comment: That's the kind of error I'm going through in the program I'm making right now.

Comment: Yeah, good old assembly...thankfully there's stackoverflow to help with that.

Comment: My best guess is that you are using MinGW with a 32 bit tool chain, and _LD_ doesn't support Win64. I use Msys2 (64-bit) for development these days instead of MinGW.

Comment: That is what happened, and thank you  for suggesting another one.

Comment: You can also use [JLink](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwlink/). It's another linker for Win64. Especially good in combination with `JWasm`(MASM syntax assembler).

Comment: Cool, I will check that out too.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer (yes, even to your own question) rather than editing it into the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:** I used LD as my linker. LD was created with linux in mind, so it was never built to compile a win64 object file.

**Solution:** Compile using a linker for Windows. Credit goes to I8086, who suggested GoLinker at [godevtool.com](http://godevtool.com), which worked perfectly.

More thanks to Michael Petch, who suggested using Msys2 instead of MinGW to compile for win64, and zx485, who told me about using JLink and JWasm.